# Show more data in endless listview when click on button - flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to show more data in list view or grid view when I click a button in Flutter? (With listview is endless) I want to do the same as the Lifeline Game image below.
Thank you!
[Lifeline Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IveaC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a List of questions

```
List<String> allQuestions = ['question1', 'question2', 'question3'];
```

Create a list view using a ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: allQuestions.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Container(child: Text(allQuestions[i]));
   },
)
```

If you add items to the list and set state the list will be recreated

```
allQuestions.add("question4");
setState((){});
```

This will populate the 4th question as the last item.